# How to add Event Grid filter in blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

i want to create an event grid trigger that will execute only when there is a file upload with name other then metadata.json

i simple word i want event trigger to run only when file name is not metadata.json

[image]

Comment: Your requirement can't achieve now. This is the feedback of the operator: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid/suggestions/35997100-advancedfilters-2018-09-15-preview-add-more-op You can do a upvote.

Comment: sure @ Bowman Zhu

Answer (score 0):

No, for event grid, there doesn't have such an operator to achieve your requirement.

> **The available operators for numbers are:**
>
> `NumberGreaterThan`
>
> `NumberGreaterThanOrEquals`
>
> `NumberLessThan`
>
> `NumberLessThanOrEquals`
>
> `NumberIn`
>
> `NumberNotIn`
>
> **The available operator for booleans is:**
>
> `BoolEquals`
>
> **The available operators for strings are:**
>
> `StringContains`
>
> `StringBeginsWith`
>
> `StringEndsWith`
>
> `StringIn`
>
> `StringNotIn`

There doesn't have an operator which is 'string not contains'. So your idea cannot be realized now.

This is the offcial doc, you can have a check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering#advanced-filtering

Comment: i just want to know can we create this event grid through some script also?

Comment: @MohitSingh I never did it, but it should be possible to create an event grid using a script. You can check the official documentation of event grid. If you don't have more doubts, can we end this ques now?

Comment: @MohitSingh Is this that you want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/scripts/event-grid-cli-create-custom-topic#sample-script

Comment: not this but i want cmd where i can add advance filter also

Comment: @MohitSingh Why do you want to use cmd to add Advanced filter?